# Как правильно указать куки

Tags: php, cookie, сессия

Помогите пожалуйста установить правильно куки и сессии. 
Вот  скрипт но она не работает:

```
    <?session_start();?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
 $link = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site', 'root', '');
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM accreg WHERE mail = ?");
$stmt->execute([$_POST['mail']]);
$data = $stmt->fetch();

if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $data['password']))
{

$_SESSION['id'] = $data['id']; 
$_SESSION['mail'] = $data['mail'];
setcookie('mail', $data['mail'], time()+60*60*24*30); 
} else {
    echo "invalid";
}
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А можно вопрос? Что здесь вообще происходит.. Вижу проверку пароля, вижу что в куки записывается почта, вижу что кнопка срабатывает.. А что нужно то? По этому коду вообще не понятны действия.. Нужна авторизация? Или что вообще

Comment: в
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Open_server\OSPanel\domains\maysite\chek.php:9) in C:\Open_server\OSPanel\domains\maysite\chek.php on line 21

Comment: Эта ошибка вызвана тем, что сначала у вас выводится какой-либо текст, а потом вы ставите сессию. Сессия должна начинаться в самом верху страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Уберите пробелы и сохраните файл в формате without bom в вашем текстовом редакторе.

[wikipedia:](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

> Маркер последовательности байтов или метка порядка байтов (англ. Byte Order Mark (BOM)) — Юникод-символ, используемый для индикации порядка байтов текстового файла. Его кодовый символ U+FEFF. По спецификации, его использование не является обязательным, однако, если маркер последовательности байтов используется, то он должен быть установлен в начале текстового файла. Помимо своего конкретного использования в качестве указателя порядка байтов, символ может также указать, какой кодировкой Unicode закодирован текст.

Кодировка Unicode может использовать 16-разрядные или 32-разрядные числа и приложение должно знать, как дальше с ними поступать. Поэтому потребность в маркере последовательности байтов возникает при обмене документами.